# bootstrap 4.6 model relatedtarget event

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to follow the example given in the bootstrap 4.6 docs here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/modal/#varying-modal-content

I have taken their example and started to adapt it to try it out and here is what I have so far:

```js
/// function for the missing promo form that puts the data from the different promos into the pop up model where you edit or create a new promo.
$("#EditPromoModal").on("show.bs.modal", function (event) {
    console.log("Edit Promo Model event fired.");
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal

    // Extract info from data-* attributes
    var promoid = button.data("promo-id");
    var promoname = button.data("promo-name");
    var promostatus = button.data("promo-status");
    var promoactivefrom = button.data("promo-activefrom");
    var promoactiveuntil = button.data("promo-activeuntil");
    var promodestinationemails = button.data("promo-destinationemails");
    var promoextraff1 = button.data("promo-extraff1");
    var promoextraff2 = button.data("promo-extraff2");
    var promoextraff3 = button.data("promo-extraff3");
    var promoextradd = button.data("promo-extradd");
    var promoextraddvalues = button.data("promo-extraddvalues");
    var promoextradd2 = button.data("promo-extradd2");
    var promoextradd2values = button.data("promo-extradd2values");

    // Update the pop up modal's content based on the value data values.
    var modal = $(this);
    modal.find("#editing-promo-title").text("Editing Promo: " + promoname);
    modal.find("#PromoName").val(promoname);
});
```

But the event does not seem to fire when I click the link in question.

The model ID is correct for the JS:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="EditPromoModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="EditPromoModal" aria-hidden="true">
```

The button that triggers it:

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="promoform_action mx-1" data-toggle="modal"
                                    data-target="#EditPromoModal"
                                    data-promo-id="<?php echo $ListCurrentPromosRow['id']; ?>"
                                    data-promo-name="<?php echo $ListCurrentPromosRow['name']; ?>"
                                    data-promo-status="<?php echo $ListCurrentPromosRow['status']; ?>"
                                    data-promo-activefrom="<?php echo $ListCurrentPromosRow['startdate']; ?>"
                                    data-promo-activeuntil="<?php echo $ListCurrentPromosRow['enddate']; ?>"
                                    data-promo-destinationemails="<?php echo $ListCurrentPromosRow['email']; ?>"
                                    data-promo-extraff1="<?php echo $ListCurrentPromosRow['extraformfield1']; ?>"
                                    data-promo-extraff2="<?php echo $ListCurrentPromosRow['extraformfield2']; ?>"
                                    data-promo-extraff3="<?php echo $ListCurrentPromosRow['extraformfield3']; ?>"
                                    data-promo-extradd="<?php echo $ListCurrentPromosRow['extraddfield']; ?>"
                                    data-promo-extraddvalues="<?php echo $ListCurrentPromosRow['extraddfieldvalues']; ?>"
                                    data-promo-extradd2="<?php echo $ListCurrentPromosRow['extraddfield2']; ?>"
                                    data-promo-extradd2values="<?php echo $ListCurrentPromosRow['extraddfield2values']; ?>"><i
                                        class="fa fa-edit" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="auto"
                                        title="Edit Promo"></i></a>
```

The button is a anchor instead of a button, but from looking at the example, I don't think that would make any different, it only talks about an element?

I can see in firefox inspector that the JS file where the above js is stored is being loaded on the page and that my backend PHP is correctly fillinng in the values for all the data objects.

I'm staring at it and can't see anything wrong, so maybe I'm doing something really silly and just can't see it.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: Is the HTML of a single button from the page source valid? Maybe some problem with the quotes. Also you're missing the `data-target="#exampleModal"` I think it's important.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? In the code I have shown, the html of the <a> link appears to be valid in the Firefox inspector, and I have the data-target specified, you can see it in my question, only it's called EditPromoModal, not examplemodal. This is reflected in th HTML ID and in the JS, so I don't think that is a problem?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the problem. There is nothing faulty with the above code. I had another unrelated JS error in the same JS file that I had foolishly assumed would not cause a problem with this one, when I fixed that one, this one started working. Thanks for your time.